# connect peers in gun db

Tags: javascript, gun

I need to understand how to connect peers in gun db. I have a socket.io server deployed on heroku but I don't know if it will work with gun. Can anyone with experience with gun db help me with this? I've readed the documentations but it's not clear how the peers are connected and there isn't a clear code example on the documentation.

I've tested the chat example, but it will not work on my localhost server, I will not be able to deploy it on my shared hosting because sockets are not permitted. Also on localhost messages are not delivered between two different browser windows.

### UPDATE :

Here is the code with the suggested `lib/webrtc` added. Still not working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Converse</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    .chat__heading {
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .chat__form-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .chat__form {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 2px solid white;
      max-width: 900px;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .chat__name-input {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .chat__message-input {
      flex: 5;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .chat__submit {
      padding: 10px;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .chat__submit:hover::after {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .chat__submit:focus::after {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .chat__submit::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: background-color 0.3s;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }

    .chat__message-list {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      flex: 1;
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding: 60px 20px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .chat__message {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 900px;
    }

    .chat__name {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .chat__when {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 2em;
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(100%, 100%, 100%, 0.9);
      opacity: 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .chat__message:hover .chat__when {
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0em;
    }

    @media (max-width: 567px) {
      .chat__heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chat hue2 page">
    <h2 id='title' class="chat__heading hue2 whitet">Have a Conversation...</h2>
    <ul class="chat__message-list">
      <li class="none"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="chat__form-container hue2">
      <form class="chat__form">
        <label for="name-input" class="visually-hidden">Name</label>
        <input id="name-input" class="chat__name-input" placeholder="Name"></input>
        <label for="message-input" class="visually-hidden">Message</label>
        <input id="message-input" class="chat__message-input" placeholder="Write a message..."></input>
        <button class="chat__submit say hue2">say</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="model">
      <li class="chat__message white huet2 box">
        <b class="chat__name"></b>
        <p class="chat__message-text"></p>
        <span class="sort none">0</span>
        <div class="chat__when"></div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../../gun.js"></script>
  <script src="../../nts.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/webrtc.js"></script>
  <script>
    var gun = Gun(document.location.host + ':443/gun');
    var chat = gun.get('converse/' + location.hash.slice(1));
    console.log(chat);
    console.log(gun);
    console.log(location.hash.slice(1));

    $(".chat__submit").on('click', submit);
    $(".chat_form").on('keydown', enter);
    function enter(e) {
      if (e.which !== 13) { return }
      submit(e);
    }
    function submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var msg = { when: Gun.time.is() };

      msg.who = $('.chat__name-input').val();
      if (!msg.who) {
        msg.who = 'user' + Gun.text.random(3);
        $('.chat__name-input').val(msg.who);
      }

      msg.what = $('.chat__message-input').val();
      if (!msg.what) { return }

      chat.set(msg);
      $('.chat__message-input').val('').focus();
    }

    chat.map().val(function (msg, id) {
      if (!msg) { return }
      var messageList = $('.chat__message-list');
      var last = sort(msg.when, messageList.children('li').last());

      var li = $("#msg-" + id)[0]; // grab if exists
      if (!li) {
        li = $('.model li').clone(true) // else create it
          .attr('id', 'msg-' + id)
          .insertAfter(last);
      }

      // bind the message data into the UI
      li = $(li);
      li.find('.chat__name').text(msg.who);
      li.find('.chat__message-text').text(msg.what);
      li.find('.sort').text(msg.when);

      var time = new Date(msg.when);
      li.find('.chat__when').text(time.toDateString() + ', ' + time.toLocaleTimeString());

      $('html, body').stop(true, true)
        .animate({ scrollTop: messageList.height() });
    });

    function sort(num, li) { return parseFloat(num) >= parseFloat($(li).find('.sort').text() || -Infinity) ? li : sort(num, li.prev()) }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: GUN does automatic peer signaling and discovery with the lib/webrtc module (https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/537). To understand better how gundb works you can research this link https://medium.com/a-weekend-with/a-weekend-with-gun-a61fdcb8cc5d, and examples https://github.com/amark/gun/tree/master/examples you can find a chat example, and here: https://gun.eco/docs/Todo-Dapp, a tutorial. In the first link you will find several server configurations (hapi, express, plain http server, etc).

Comment: @MauroStepanoski I've seen the chat example but there is no trace of the `lib/webrtc` that is mentioned in the interactive dapp tutorial and is supposed to connect peers. I need to create private chat rooms so I'm not sure if gun will connect the peers that are on the same url unique link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wow @mauro-stepanoski 's comment is so good (it should be the answer)! @jihuuNI when the `lib/webrtc` adapter is added like in the Todo-Dapp tutorial, it attempts to automatically connect all browsers with all other browsers - in the future, AXE will automatically cut off unnecessary connections. Do note, browser's WebRTC feature is not very reliable, so you still want to also have super peer connections.

Comment: As I wrote, I've tested the chat example that is present in the example folder and the `lib/webRTC` library isn't loaded in the `index.html` file, so it will try to use websockets. The documentation and examples need to be more clear about peers, but maybe I'm the stupid one.!

Comment: this is what I get in the consolle also if I load the webrtc.js library: `{err: "Error: No ACK received yet.", lack: true}`